# Not in the sudoers file, but I am member of the group sudo and that group is in sudoers

Tags: sudo

I tried exectuting a command.

```
me@intern:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for me: 
me is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

But I am in the `sudo` group

```
me@intern:~$ groups
sudo
```

/ets/sudoers :

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

john ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apache2 reload
john ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service apache2 restart
john ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vi /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What your `sudoers` file is showing is that a *user* called `sudo` may use `sudo`.  If you want to add the *group* called `sudo`, then do it as is done with the `admin` group, i.e. add a `%` in front of the group name:

```
%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

(If the `admin` group is not in use by anyone on the system, I would remove its `sudo` permissions at the same time.)

Group names are prefixed with `%`, while usernames don't have a prefix.

Additionally, numerical UIDs and GIDs may be used with `#`:

```
#1000 ALL= ...

%#1000 ALL= ...
```